# Pagination with Sphinx

Tags: php, mysqli, sphinx

Using Sphinx with standard MySQL using the query

```
    $sql = "SELECT  *,WEIGHT() AS score FROM tableindex WHERE     {$matchagainst} ORDER BY score LIMIT {$page},100 OPTION ranker=bm25,index_weights=(name=10, keywords=3) ";
```

I would like to paginate the results. Using typical MySQL the result set would only be 100 rows given this query but Sphinx does not regard the $page as an offset. Instead say $page was equal to 10 then Sphinx would also include 1000 results in the count even though it is actually returning 100 rows.

Is this a bug or is their some other way of paginating results in Sphinx and only return the row count and the rows that come AFTER the $page offset?

Answer (score 0):

the total and total_found in SHOW META, always count all rows **without** regard to the offset and  limit.

if you are getting 100 rows of data then everything is working as it should.

Sort of like SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS from mysql

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have read many of your articles on the Sphinx site and am a big fan. Given the above example only the expected 100 results are indeed being returned however the max_matches are accounting for the 100 results in the set AND the 1000 matches before the result set. In the config file I have max_matches set at a fairly high value and have even set it relatively high in the query. Shouldn't the max_matches be equal to the row limit instead of the offset+limit? I am using Sphinx for product pagination and depending on the query there could very well be a large number.